# SwiftUI: How to stop Text topline from moving down when text font size increases?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I stop `Text` topline from moving down when the text font size increases?

I tried using the `.baselineOffset()` modifier, but it didn't work.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SquareText: View {
    @State private var fontSize: CGFloat = 22
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Text 1")
                        .font(.system(size: fontSize, weight: .bold))
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Long Text 2")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
            .background { Color.red }
            
            .frame(maxWidth: 350, maxHeight: 190)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
            .centeredHorizontally()
            .padding()
                        
            HStack {
                Text("Font Size: \(fontSize.formatted())")
                Slider(value: $fontSize, in: 22...100, step: 1)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the CenteredHorizontally ViewModifier:

```
// Centered Horizontally View Modifier
struct CenteredHorizontally: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            content
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
extension View {
    func centeredHorizontally() -> some View {
        modifier(CenteredHorizontally())
    }
}
```